# How to print Array READABLE

Tags: php, format, var-dump

How do i print an Array readable? print_r($array); and var_dump($array); both produce some very ugly clutter of that $array. Ok it is what it says, it prints that array, but i'd like to have some well formated print of that array, how do i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it is well-formatted but HTML ignores line breaks and double spaces.

You just have to view the page's source code (CTRL+U or right-click > view source code)

Answer (score 3):

```
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($array);
echo '</pre>';
```

Or to a better yet performance, use xDebug with 
    html_colors = on.
html_colors can be found on php.ini file.
xdebug is from http://xdebug.org/download.php

With xDebug and Colors you don't need to use

```
echo '<pre>';
echo '</pre>';
```

it's beautiful as-is.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your `var_dump()` output in `<pre>` to preserve the monospacing:

```
echo "<pre>" . var_dump($array) . "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<pre>".print_r($array, true)."</pre>";
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
$myArray=array("a","b","c");

foreach($myArray as $A)
{
echo $A."<br/>"; // you can use any style here like table, div span etc...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I like:

```
highlight_string(var_export($array, true));
```

`var_export()` is usable (copy/paste) PHP code as well.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to see it well formatted, you can encode it to json object and print it pretty :)

You have to do is:

```
echo json_encode($array,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT); //This needs PHP 5.3 at least.
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. PHP Version 5.3.26 running. Notice: Use of undefined constant JSON_PRETTY_PRINT - assumed 'JSON_PRETTY_PRINT' in /srv/www/htdocs/web682/html/cal/functions.php on line 77

Warning: json_encode() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given in /srv/www/htdocs/web682/html/cal/functions.php on line 77