# PHP explode() not working

Tags: php, arrays, explode

I am a beginner to php and i have some trouble with the explode() function.

```
if (isset($_GET["url"])) {
        $url = $_GET["url"];
        $url = explode("/", $url);
        echo $url;
        $controller = $url[0];
        $action     = $url[1];
    } else {
        $controller = "pages";
        $action     = "home";
    }
```

I am typing in the url "localhost/pages/home" and the echo is just printing "Array" as if it's empty. If i echo the $url before using the explode function it comes out as "pages/home". Thanks in advance.

Comment: `$_GET["url"]` would be the value of a query string parameter, such as `http://localhost?url=foo/bar`.  Since you don't have a `url=` in your `localhost/pages/home` url, `$_GET["url"]` is not set and so you always get the `else`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print Array READABLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24895421/how-to-print-array-readable)

Answer (score 3):

`explode()` returns the string that you separated as an array(), so PHP's `echo` doesn't support outputs of array. You must use `print_r()` or `var_dump()` functions to do that.

```
if (isset($_GET["url"])) {
    $url = $_GET["url"];
    $url = explode("/", $url);
    print_r($url);
    $controller = $url[0];
    $action     = $url[1];
} else {
    $controller = "pages";
    $action     = "home";
}
```

Comment: Not `print()` for arrays, just `print_r()` or more favoured IMO as it shows line numbers and data type, `var_dump()`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is likely with your input. The $GET['url'] is not how you access the URL unless you are setting it. You probably want: $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']:

```
var_dump($_GET["url"]); 
var_dump($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']); 
var_dump($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
```

See [PHP Server Variables](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php).

**Test this:**

    `$url = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49765341/php-explode-not-working";
    $url = explode("/", $url);
    var_dump($url);
    die();`

**Output**

```
C:\wamp64\www\blink\vendor\bausch\yii2-purevision\views\report\index.php:75:
array (size=6)
  0 => string 'https:' (length=6)
  1 => string '' (length=0)
  2 => string 'stackoverflow.com' (length=17)
  3 => string 'questions' (length=9)
  4 => string '49765341' (length=8)
  5 => string 'php-explode-not-working' (length=23)
```

`

Answer (score 1):

**[`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)** **forms** an array, comprised of the components that were split up. When you give it the string `localhost/pages/home`, it forms three components: `localhost`, `pages` and `home`.

Using **[`echo()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php)** to output the contents will output the array **itself**, and just show `Array`. If you want to output the **contents** of the array, you either need to use [**`var_dump()`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) or **[`print_r()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php)**:

```
<?php

$url = 'localhost/pages/home';
$url = explode("/", $url);
var_dump($url);
```

Returns:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(9) "localhost"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "pages"
  [2]=>
  string(4) "home"
}
```

This can aloso be seen **[at 3v4l](https://3v4l.org/MTCB9)**.

If you want to grab an individual line, you will need to access it by index with `echo $url[index]`. For example, `echo $url[2]` will give you `home`.